# Find char* element in array of char* in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, void

I'm trying to write function that search for `char *` element in array of `char*` and the function start check this element, if the element exist in the array I will have "found", if not it should be "inserted" and the element added to the array.

I wrote this code but I cannot know how to try it, the program always gives me exception, what can I do to check the element in my pointer array?

```
void checkFunction(char*myArray[], char *element,bool flag)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*myArray) ; ++i)
    {
        if (myArray[i] == element)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    *myArray = element;
    flag = false;

    if (flag)
    {
        cout << "Found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Inserted" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't ready to use poiners and arrays, which are advanced low-level language features for experts. Please use `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: When you compare a char pointer with another char pointer, you're not comparing their values. You're comparing their positions on memory. You have to check them like that: strcmp(a, b) == 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ Way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<string> myStrings { "One", "Two", "Three" };

    // std::find()  finds the first element that matches a value
    auto it = find(begin(myStrings), end(myStrings),  "Twooo");
    if (it != end(myStrings)) {
        cout << "We found this string; do something..." << endl;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks regarding your function:

1.Why do you need the third parameter `bool flag`, instead of having it as local variable?

2.If you want to expand an array you should copy the old to a newly allocated and then add the new element, you can not just do:  `*myArray = element;`

3.If you want to iterate through the array length/ size, instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*myArray) ; ++i)
```

pass an additional parameter to your function, that indicates the number of elements in the array.

With `std::string` and `std::vector` you could do something like:

```
void check_insert (std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string& c) {

    for (auto i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] == c) {
            std::cout << "Found!\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    v.push_back(c);
    std::cout << "Inserted!\n";
}
```

Comment: Mostly good. But I think your `for` loop with `arr_begin`, `arr_end` is wrong. Each of those is a pointer to a `char*` anywhere in memory, not the location of the array elements themselves. itself. `for(auto i = myArray; i != &myArray[n];++i)`

Comment: @Keith a pointer to the first element of an array, when incremented `n` times, where `n = array-size` will 100% reach the last element, as "an array is a homogeneous sequence of objects allocated in **contiguous memory**."

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, your now deleted code was setting `arr_begin` to the value contained in first element, not the address of the first element.